# checkbox 2d array

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

I have a very tricky situation. I have a list of skills each with a level of 1,2,3 which are represented as check boxes besides each skill name. These skills are pulled out of a database. Without skill levels, the normal thing would be to assign the value of the checkbox to be the ID of the skill ( which goes into the checkbox array ). Is there any way to store the values in a 2 dimensional array so that I can access the skill which was checked and also the skill level that was checked?
I also need to validate these via Javascript so that the maximum skill level of all the skills that the user chooses does not exceed 5.

This is the code I have written but I cannot retrieved the checked values via Javascript:

```
$sql = "select * from Skill where Active=1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $count=0;
    echo '<tr>';
    while ($rr=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    echo '<td>';
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skill[][".$rr['SkillID']."]\" value=\"1\" /><span></span></input>";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skill[][".$rr['SkillID']."]\" value=\"2\" /><span></span></input>";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"skill[][".$rr['SkillID']."]\" value=\"3\" /><span>".$rr['Name']."</span></input>";
    echo '</td>';
    $count++;
    if ($count % 3 == 0)
    {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use single quotes in your `echo` statements so that you don't have to have all those ugly escapes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input ... name=\"skill[][".$rr['SkillID']."\" ... />
```

Try

```
<input ... name=\"skill[]\" id=\"skill_".$rr['SkillID']."\" value=\"1" ... />
```

Then, to determine the total skill level checked, you can use jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $("input[name=skill[]]").click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $("input[name=skill[]]:checked").each(function() {
            total += $(this).val();
        });
        if (total > 5) {
            alert("Skill level too high.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can find out which skill is checked with this kind of `name`.

Comment: @Snow AFAIK you can - I've used similar syntax, the only change being I quoted the name, like this: `$('input[name="foo"]')`. I'm not sure how jQuery will handle unquoted strings.

Comment: @JamWaffles AFAIK jquery will handle `input[name=whatever]` the same as it will handle `input[name="whatever"]`.

Comment: @JamWaffles No problem on the client side, because `id` attribute is unique among checkboxes in this answer. But what about the server-side, I mean when the form is posted? You can't distinguish which skill is checked if you `name` all inputs like `skill[]`, can you?.

Comment: @SnowBlind that's when it's time to get a little creative. `value="1_{$rr['SkillID']}"` would work just fine (as long as you split its value in the jQuery function). OR you could give the input a `level` attribute and check that through jQuery using `$(this).attr("level")`.

Comment: @JamWaffles That's absolutely true but Matt didn't use such `value`s. But yeah, I think I've made my point :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<input name="skill[SKILL_ID][1]" value=1>
<input name="skill[SKILL_ID][2]" value=1>
<input name="skill[SKILL_ID][3]" value=1>
.
.
.
<input name="skill[NEXT_SKILL_ID][1]" value=1>
<input name="skill[NEXT_SKILL_ID][2]" value=1>
<input name="skill[NEXT_SKILL_ID][3]" value=1>
```